# HTML - crop background image width when resize browser

Tags: html, css

I have a lead background image which is positioned right. I want to achieve when resizing the browser window, that the bg image will be cropped from right side.

Now it is only moving along the browser window, but I need to crop the right size as I resize it.

My current code:

```
 <div style="background: url(assets/img/leadspace.jpg) top right no-repeat #1d2f93;height: 360px;"></div>
```

Comment: should be easy with media queries

Comment: use fixed width to make it cropped from the right side

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have 2 columns. In left column I have text, in right column the background only. Making the 2nd column fixed width doesn't crop the background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `background-size: auto; background-repeat: no-repeat;` remove the top and right align. if you want `top right` alignment for higher version(desktop view) use media query.

[check the demo](https://codepen.io/balajidesigner/pen/ZVMomg)

Comment: yes, this seems working as expected. I will then need the blue column to be always  visible and just to crop the background, not also the blue column, but I will manage that. My question was answered, thank you!